# Best way to destructing function Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

What's the best way to destruction by javascript (in terms of performance).

```
{items.map((item) => {
const {value1, value2} = option
return (<li>{value1} {value2}</li>)}
```

OR

```
{items.map(({value1, value2}) =>  (
<li>{value1} {value2}</li>
)
```

Is destruction in props when map item good for performance?

Comment: I suspect that plain dot notation is faster than destructuring - but performance really shouldn't matter for something like this, readability is a much greater concern

Comment: Many things are optimized by the compiler. So It's hard to always tell what really happens and what is really more performant. Nothing better than testing for yourself in your particular environment and scenario.